# how to reuse angularjs bar chart directive in multiple divs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am newbie for angularjs.. can anyone please tell me, are directives reusable? if yes how can we use them?

I have one bar chart directive :

```
directive('bars1', function ($parse) {

  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
         data: '=',
         label: '@'
       },
       replace: true,

     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

       var chart = d3.select('#chart')
         .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
         .selectAll('div')
         .data(scope.data).enter()
         .append("div")
         .transition().ease("elastic")
         .style("width", function(d) { return (d/1000)-10 + "%"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d ; });
     } 
  };
  })
```

I want to use  directive in 2 different divs like this

```
<div id="dashboard1" >
   <div id="bars" style="margin-top:20%">

     <div id="chart">
          <bars1  data=val></bars1> 
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<div id="dashboard2" >
   <div id="bars" style="margin-top:20%" >

     <div id="chart">
          <bars1  data=val></bars1> 
     </div>
     </div>


</div>
```

but it's not creating 2 separate charts in two divs but creating only one chart in first div. please help me.

Comment: Try to replace d3.select('#chart') with  d3.select(element[0]) .

Comment: thanks riteshmeher, it worked...

Comment: glad it helped you. I have added it as answer. you may mark it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `d3.select('#chart')` with `d3.select(element[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `directive`:

```
directive('bars1', function ($parse) {

  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
         data: '=',
         label: '@'
       },
       replace: true,

     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

       var chart = d3.select(scope.label)//<--use element id rather than specific
         .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
         .selectAll('div')
         .data(scope.data).enter()
         .append("div")
         .transition().ease("elastic")
         .style("width", function(d) { return (d/1000)-10 + "%"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d ; });
     } 
  };
  })
```

And you html:

```
<div id="dashboard1" >
   <div id="bars" style="margin-top:20%">

     <div id="chart1"><!--use different id -->
          <bars1  data="val" label="#chart1"></bars1> 
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<div id="dashboard2" >
   <div id="bars" style="margin-top:20%" >

     <div id="chart2"><!--use different id -->
          <bars1  data="val" label="#chart2"></bars1> 
     </div>
     </div>


</div>
```

Comment: it's not working Yin... but thank u so much for answer